# GAS get status of trigger (if disabled then delete)

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I have disabled time.based triggers that are created from within a function. These tend to accumulate, so I created this script to remove the triggers, which seems to work.

Ideally though I only want to remove the triggers when the status = disabled. How can I get the status of a trigger? Is this possible?

```
function deleteTriggers() {

var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id');
var triggers = ScriptApp.getUserTriggers(doc);
// Log the handler function for the first trigger in the array.

Logger.log("triggers length" + triggers.length)

for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {

  if(triggers[i].getHandlerFunction() == "name of function") {
  ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);  
  Logger.log("trigger deleted" + triggers[i].getHandlerFunction());

  } // if 
 } // loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

There is the method `isDisabled()` that is not documented in th eApps Script documentation, however works corrects to assess eithe a trigger has been disabled.

### Example:
´´´
function myFunction() {
disabled = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers()[0].isDisabled()
console.log(disabled)
}
´´´

### Unfortunately there is no direct way to retrieve programmatically either a trigger is disabled

- However, with the exception of [specific cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61590985/google-apps-script-recursive-schedule-trigger) usually only clock trigger can be disabled - when they expire. So you can narrow down your results by specifying

`if(triggers[i].getEventType() == "CLOCK")`

or

`if(triggers[i].getTriggerSource() == "CLOCK")`.

- If you want to take a step further, with the [Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api) you can inderectly retrieve the execution time of a function through [Processes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/processes).
- The `Resource: Process` gives you information about executed functions including their name and [Process type](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/processes#ProcessType).
- Process type `TIME_DRIVEN` specifies that the function has been run by a time-based trigger. You can retrieve the corresponding `Process` `startTime`.
- So, if the `functionName` of a function executed in the past on time-driven trigger corresponds to `triggers[i].getHandlerFunction()` and `triggers[i].getEventType() == "CLOCK"`, you can assume that the corresponding
  trigger has already been fired in the past and thus, is disabled now.
- This is certainly a convoluted workaround and might not work if you have different time-driven triggers bound to the same handler function.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (triggers[i].isDisabled() == true)
```

Comment: This method seems to be undocumented, but it's working.